# How to connect to AWS MSK Cluster from C# using Identity and Access Management (IAM) authorization

Tags: c#, amazon-iam, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I have an AWS MSK (Kafka) Broker. It has been setup for public access authenticating with IAM. I know the broker settings are correct, I have been using https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth to successfully connect to the broker as both a consumer and producer **written in Java**. However I also have a requirement to write a C# consumer. Ideally, I would like to find a C# library  that is equivalent to the java aws-msk-iam-auth library (probably some nuGet package). I can't find any such library or even any way to connect to an AWS MSK Broker using IAM authentication in C#. So my question: How do I connect to an AWS MSK Broker using IAM authentication from C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, the answer is that in order to use IAM from C# I have to write code that does, in C#, the same thing that https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth does in Java. I don't understand why AWS hasn't done this. They did it for Java. Another option, if I still want to use AWS, is to self-host Kafka on an EC2 and not use MSK or IAM at all. That's probably the best solution.

Comment: I'm also on the project that requires to connect to public AWS MSK. Have you had any success connecting a .Net app running in a local machine using IAM?

Found this IAM signer for .net (https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-sasl-signer-net#getting-started) and plan to use the confluent kafka library,

Comment: I stopped using AWS MSK.  Use Kafka hosted on an EC2....